# Event Listing - Number of Participants

Tags: civievent, joomla, hooks, 4.6.10

Is there a way to add a column to the front end Event Listing that shows the total number of participants registered for that row's event?

This is the com_civcrm >> Event Listing menu item.

[image: Add a column for participant count.]

The column would total and display the number of registered participants.

Comment: Can you clarify which screen you mean exactly? A screenshot might help.

Comment: I've updated the original question to include a visual and a better explanation.